# How to design the class with generic class property in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Need to design the class structure to return a json result of the below format :

```
{
   "data":{
      "response":{
         "id":1,
         "name":"Ram",
         "address":"abc"
      }
   },
   "error":{
      "code":"",
      "message":""
   },
   "success":true
}
```

The "response" class need to be generic.

Comment: So, what is the actual problem? What have you done so far, what have you tried?

Comment: What he has done so far, written 2 sentences and copy pasted the data format. Actual problem is that he cannot write code, and what he has tried so far is googling about his problem but couldn't find any results but found about this site and then created a login and posted this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally there are tools like https://jsonutils.com/ and http://json2csharp.com/ which can help you out.

Also Visual Studio provides such functionality: Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Class

Anyway, I used jsonutils.com to generate this code for you:

```
public class Response
{

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{

    [JsonProperty("response")]
    public Response Response { get; set; }
}

public class Error
{

    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Data Data { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("error")]
    public Error Error { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}
```

As for creating something generic, you can do something like this:

```
public class GenericExample<T>
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public T Data { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("error")]
    public Error Error { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}

var ge = GenericExample<Response>();
```